# Hello I am having trouble finding out if I approached this problem the right way

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

*Find x*
$$(3x-4)^{2x^2+2} =(3x-4)^{5x}$$

*Iv'e proceeded by evaluating different cases.*

1. *First case both bases = 1 and exponent is arbitrary*
   $$\implies 3x-4=1$$
   $$\therefore x=\frac{5}{3}$$
2. *Second case both bases = 0 and exponent is arbitrary*
   $$\implies 3x-4=0$$
   $$\therefore x=\frac{4}{3}$$
3. *Third and final is that both bases are equal so we solve for exponents*
   $$\implies2x^{2}+2=5x$$
   $$\therefore x= \frac{1}{2}$$or$$ x=2$$

*Are these all the possible solutions? Am I missing something? Any insight would be of much help.*

Comment: $x=2$ is the only solution but none of your working makes sense. In the third case you say that we need both bases to be equal so we must have $3x-4=x-4\implies x=0$ but then the exponents are not equal because $2=2x^2+2\ne 5x=0$. The solution $x=2$ comes when the bases have the same absolute value and the exponents are both the same and even.

Comment: @PeterForeman I made a typo writing the initial question.

Comment: You might also consider (and eliminate) the case where both bases $= -1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But are the other cases alright?

Comment: $3x -4 = -1$ and $2x^2 +2$ and $5x$ are the same parity.  ($x=1$ and $2x^2 + 2= 4$ and $5x = 5$ so impossible-- but must be considered.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're dealing with real values alone throughout.

I would proceed as you do in stage (3) above, then substitute $x=2,\,1/2$ into $3x-4$ to see whether I get negative or positive values. Thus, if $x=2,$ we have that $3x-4=3(2)-4=6-4>0,$ so this is a solution. If $x=1/2$ we have that $3x-4=3(1/2)-4<0.$ Thus this cannot be a solution since $(-y^2)^{1/2}$ is not real-valued.

As for your other numbers, they work. Since there no other bases whose arbitrary powers always yield the same *real* value, then your set is complete.

Comment: But if $$x=\frac{3}{5}$$ then the exponent wouldn't matter since 1 raised to any number is still 1

Comment: @VicenteMartinez Oh. I see the point now. I was implicitly assuming positive base different from $1.$ I'm used to thinking in terms of the exponential *functions.* But yes, you're right.